# Add new column to sites page

Tags: multisite, actions, columns

I'm trying to get info into my network sites page in a column.  Below works great to grab the network site ID for each site.

How can I make it display the option_value for the item (blog_expire) in the option_name column within my blogname_options table?

```
class Add_Blog_ID {
public static function init() {
    $class = __CLASS__ ;
    if ( empty( $GLOBALS[ $class ] ) )
        $GLOBALS[ $class ] = new $class;
}
public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'wpmu_blogs_columns', array( $this, 'get_id' ) );
    add_action( 'manage_sites_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'manage_blogs_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'add_style' ) );
}
public function add_columns( $column_name, $blog_id ) {
    if ( 'blog_id' === $column_name )
        echo $blog_id;
    return $column_name;
}
// Add in a column header
public function get_id( $columns ) {
    $columns['blog_id'] = __('ID');
    return $columns;
}
public function add_style() {
    echo '<style>#blog_id { width:7%; }</style>';
}
}
add_action( 'init', array( 'Add_Blog_ID', 'init' ) );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a modified version of your class that should work:

```
class Add_Blog_ID {
    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__ ;
        if ( empty( $GLOBALS[ $class ] ) )
            $GLOBALS[ $class ] = new $class;
    }
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'wpmu_blogs_columns', array( $this, 'get_id' ) );
        add_action( 'manage_sites_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'manage_blogs_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'add_style' ) );
    }
    public function add_columns( $column_name, $blog_id ) {
        if ( 'blog_id' === $column_name ){
            echo $blog_id;
            //render column value
        }elseif( 'blog_expire' === $column_name ){
            echo get_blog_option($blog_id,'blog_expire',"Default Value To Show if none");
        }
        return $column_name;
    }
    // Add in a column header
    public function get_id( $columns ) {
        $columns['blog_id'] = __('ID');
        //add extra header to table
        $columns['blog_expire'] = __('Blog Expires');

        return $columns;
    }
    public function add_style() {
        echo '<style>#blog_id { width:7%; }</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'init', array( 'Add_Blog_ID', 'init' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but an extra feature to JonnyPlow & Bainternet code.

I wanted the ID column at the beginning, not the end. This can be achieved this way:

```
public function get_id( $columns ) {
    $columns['blog_expire'] = __('Blog Expires');
    $in = array('blog_id' => 'ID');
    $columns = $in + $columns; // array_unshift don't work here, don't ask me why
    return $columns;
}
```

*But*, if we want to fine tune and put it as the second (or 3rd) column, then an [extra function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#106717) comes handy.

- although the `admin_footer` is harmless in other screens, I put the correct suffix for only loading in `sites.php`
- as `blog_expire` was not rendering anything for me, I changed to `template` for a quick view of what theme each site is using.

```
class Add_Blog_ID {
    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__ ;
        if ( empty( $GLOBALS[ $class ] ) )
            $GLOBALS[ $class ] = new $class;
    }
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'wpmu_blogs_columns', array( $this, 'get_id' ) );
        add_action( 'manage_sites_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'manage_blogs_custom_column', array( $this, 'add_columns' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'admin_footer-sites.php', array( $this, 'add_style' ) );
    }

    private function array_put_to_position(&$array, $object, $position, $name = null) {
        $count = 0;
        $return = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {  
                // insert new object
                if ($count == $position) {  
                        if (!$name) $name = $count;
                        $return[$name] = $object;
                        $inserted = true;
                }  
                // insert old object
                $return[$k] = $v;
                $count++;
        }  
        if (!$name) $name = $count;
        if (!$inserted) $return[$name];
        $array = $return;
        return $array;
    }

    public function add_columns( $column_name, $blog_id ) {
        if ( 'blog_id' === $column_name ) {
            echo $blog_id;
            //render column value
        } elseif ( 'template' === $column_name ) {
            echo get_blog_option($blog_id, 'template', "Default Value To Show if none");
        }
        return $column_name;
    }
    // Add in a column header
    public function get_id( $columns ) {
        $columns = $this->array_put_to_position($columns, 'ID', 1, 'blog_id');
        $columns['template'] = __('Using Theme');
        return $columns;
    }

    public function add_style() {
        echo '<style>#blog_id { width:7%; }</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'init', array( 'Add_Blog_ID', 'init' ) );
```

Comment: This is excellent! I needed the Theme for a site also to show. I had been trying current_theme. I started searching for documentation on all the available options.

Comment: Wow! This is some ancient code!! Glad it was useful :)

Comment: I have tried similar code to add a column to the Sites list page by putting code in a plugin with the appropriate filter. But plugins are not loaded on the Network, Sites page, so my filter never gets executed. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/413584/29416 and the note at the end of the question. Have not figured out a solution yet after much searching...